# Why do I have to specify (NSMutableString *) in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pointers

```
NSMutableString *stringA = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSMutableString *stringB = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
stringB = (NSMutableString *)stringA;
```

From now on, stringB points to the same address as string A. I don't understand why do I have to write this :

```
stringB = (NSMutableString *)stringA;
```

instead of this:

```
stringB = stringA
```

since both of them are already declared as NSMutableString pointers.

Comment: Please explain why you think the cast is needed (because it isn't).

Comment: I had a more complex code, and the bug was caused by something else. I also know that it can't be necessary but I was sure that this was the bug, and I've found it really awkward. I won't post the entire code , because I've found the real bug and it has nothing to do with the cast. So yes, the cast is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You don't understand it, because it is nonsense.

You created one mutable string and stored a pointer in stringA.

You created another mutable string and stored a pointer in stringB.

Then you stored the first pointer in the second variable, which will get rid of the second mutable string. The second alloc/init was just pointless, nothing but a waste of code and time. And the cast is absolutely not necessary.

Comment: stringB = stringA doesn't work, it works just with the casting, try that. Casting is necessary, else you can't store the pointer of first string in the second variable. That's what i'm asking, why is the casting necessary?

Comment: @BogdanPop - The cast **isn't** necessary.